# How to prevent an element from growing outside of its grandparent's boundaries?

Tags: html, css

I've seen a similar question answered when the element was a direct child of the container with the `max-width` set, but in my case, I have a div with dynamic content, and inside of it is another div, which is a growing list. I need this internal div to grow until the root div reaches its `max-height`, then switch to overflow.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

#anotherdiv {
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv">
  <p>
  First paragraph
  </p>
  <div id="anotherdiv">
   <div id="insideDiv">
    Some inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br>
  </div>
  </div>
  <p>
   Final paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. The trick was to set `display: flex` on the root div and on `#anotherdiv`, set `flex-shrink: 0` on all other children of both the root div and `#anotherdiv`, and finally set `height: 100%` and `overflow-y: auto` on both `#anotherdiv` and on the scrollable div. This does the trick. Full demo of my solution - https://codepen.io/calsal/pen/bGdgyBX.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add `overflow-y: auto` to `#topDiv`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 1050px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#anotherdiv {
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv">
  <p>
    First paragraph
  </p>
  <div id="anotherdiv">
    <div id="insideDiv">
      Some inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    Final paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the outermost div to remain fully visible, I think this just makes it scrollable.

Comment: Yeah, because you have `max-height` set on `#topDiv`. You can control the "fully visible" with that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I need `topDiv` to grow until it hits its max height. I dont want it to grow past a certain height. That's the main premise of my question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to change `#topDiv.max-height` to `1050px` and reduced the content in `#insideDiv`. You can  see that `#topDiv` does not grow past the size of its contents. And if you play around with it a bit, you will see (just like before editing my answer) that it will not grow past `max-height`.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you could set that max-height on `#insideDiv` instead of `#topDiv`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow-y:auto;
  max-height: 150px;
}

#anotherdiv {
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv">
  <p>
  First paragraph
  </p>
  <div id="anotherdiv">
   <div id="insideDiv">
    Some inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br>
  </div>
  </div>
  <p>
   Final paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think there's a good way to calculate it, because its max-height should be (outer div max-hight - how much height the rest of the dynamic content takes).

Answer (score 0):

```
#anotherdiv {
  max-height: 400px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.

Comment: @tacoshy Although nothing you say is wrong, your review action was wrong. Although code-only answers aren't considered great, they are still considered answers. As such, they shouldn't be deleted (only downvoted), unless they repeat much older answers on the same question.

Comment: @tacoshy the main problem with this answer really is that it does not answer my question. I cannot set `max-height` on `anotherdiv` because there is no way to compute it with CSS only.

Comment: @tacoshy sir if you have any problem with this answer you can wite code and let me know that i was doing this mistake you continuously downgrading my answers